# Debug Silverlight application on the client side

Tags: silverlight, debugging, silverlight-4.0

I got a Silverlight application which runs fine on my dev system, but it doesn't event startup on a bare client, though.

The exception is not helpful at all:

```
Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
Code: 4004    
Category: ManagedRuntimeError       
Message: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Windows.Application.Application_Starting(Object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
   at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(Int32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)
```

Whats a good procedure to get to the bottom of the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Next time get the English translation of the exception; that will make it easier for others to help you

Comment: NullReferenceException should narrow it down for you.  If that doesn't help, add error logging to your application.

Comment: Exception translated. The NullReference is faarrr away from the user code, although I know there has to be a problem in it. But how to get to the real problem?

Comment: Do you subscribe to the `Application_Starting` event? If so, show the handler code.

Comment: I think the Jounce framework does, I use version 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remotely debug the silverlight code.  There are two ways to do this:

1)  Pull up the hosted website on your dev box, attach the debugger to IE, and go from there.  A lot of people seem to call this "remote debugging", but it's really not.  [Here's a blog post](http://bryantlikes.com/DebuggingARemotelyHostedSilverlightApp.aspx) that goes into some more detail.

2)  Install a remote debugger on the end user's machine and debug it that way.  This should be just a standard remote debug procedure unless you're trying to debug it on a mac.  In that case it's still possible, but with a [different set of steps.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903948%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: What remote debugger? Where to get one of these?

Comment: All versions of Visual Studio (except Express) come with remote debuggers. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx